# How to Change the Type of a Variable in Java?

Tags: java, variables, types

I am working on a Java project and have encountered a situation where I need to change the type of a variable during runtime. Is there a way to do this in Java?

```java
void doSmth(){
        String var = "13";
        //some work with string;
        int var = -1;
        //continue program
    }
```

Later in my code, I need to treat **var** as a different type, say int or double. Is there a way to achieve this without causing type mismatch errors?

```java
void doSmth(){
    String var = "13";
    //some work with string
    var=null;
    int var = -1;
    //continue program
}
```

```
Main.java:15: error: variable var is already defined in method doSmth()
        int s = -1;
```

Comment: You can't, Java is strongly typed: a variable is linked to a type.

Comment: As others said, you cannot reuse the same variable name for different types within a scope.. I wonder what use case are you trying to solve by reusing a variable name  ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redefine a variable as a different type with the same name.
You can use Integer class method to parse a "numeric" string.

int newVariable = Integer.valueOf(var);

Btw changing type is called "casting".
If you want to change type like this you could look for "cast String to int Java"

Comment: `Integer.valueOf()` is not the best for *parsing* a string an get an `int`- it will create an instance of `Integer` which will then be converted to an `int` - `Integer.parseInt()` avoids these intermediate steps and object

Answer (score 1):

There is no Variant or Union type in Java, but you can use Object.

Something like:

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Object o = "foo";
        System.out.println("o(" + o.getClass() + ") = " + o);
        o = -1;
        System.out.println("o(" + o.getClass() + ") = " + o);
    }
}
```

If you're really just trying to reuse a variable name use {} to scope the variable:

```java
class Scratch {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        {
            String var = "foo";
            System.out.println(var);
        }
        {
            int var = 1;
            System.out.println(var);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Java is not a dynamically typed language, like Python or JavaScript. It is a strongly typed language, which means that every variable has a type associated with it and once declared a type, it cannot be changed during runtime.

You can definitely create a new variable which extracts the current value stored in a variable, there are many factory methods to do so.

```
void doSmth(){
    String var = "13";
    //some work with string;
    int var = -1;
    //continue program
}
```

As far as I can see your *var* deals only which numbers which is initially a *String* type then you wish to continue it as something of type *int*, in order to do so. You can try doing this

```
void doSmth(){
    String var = "13";
    //some work with var;
    int now = Integer.valueOf(var);
    //continue program
}
```

Here *now* will have the current value stored in *var*, unless and until *var* has something other than a number.

Or if you really don't want to initialise a new variable and only want to work with the same one, try using a variable of type *Object*. This is the superclass of all classes, therefore it can hold objects of any class. But this is not a typesafe measure, but if it's not a problem you can go on with it.

```
void doSmth(){
    Object var = "13";
    //some work with string;
    var = -1;
    //continue program
}
```

If you want two variables to be of the same name, that is impossible if they both are in the same scope, try changing the variable scope if you want to try something like that.

Comment: .valueOf() returns an object of type Integer, instead as you mentioned, Integer.parseInt() can also be done to return a direct primitive. It can be used based on the use case.

Answer (score 0):

As said, Java is strongly typed so this kind of things really aren't possible in the way you want.

There is this possibility that you can create an Object which can then hold any reference or value you wish, but I would strongly discourage using this - types are your friend.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Object obj;
    obj = 1;
    System.out.println(obj);
    obj = "asdsa";
    System.out.println(obj);
    obj = 2.0D;
    System.out.println(obj);
    obj = List.of("123", 23);
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Would print:

```
1
asdsa
2.0
[123, 23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't. But that doesn't mean you can't pass values between variables. In your case you have a `String var` that has a certain value. If you want to do something with that string and then later use the value of that string for other purposes, you can't just change the typing of that variable, but you can convert the string value into an integer value and assign it to another variable. For example:

```
void doSmth() {
    String var = "13";
    // you can do some work with this string
    // after you are done working with the string and the value of it changes
    // you may want to use that value in an integer calculation

    // lets say for the sake of this example your var = "2"
    var = "2";
    // to use the new value of var in another calculation you can change the data and assign it to a new variable
    int newVar = Integer.parseInt(var);
    // here you change the type of data and assign it to a new variable so newVar = 2
    // you can now continue working with this new variable.
}
```

This is just one example of converting one data type to another. But maybe that wasn't what you wanted to do. Maybe the two variables aren't used in the same algorithm and you just like the variable name or it makes sense. In Java variables are "visible" in a certain context and are invisible outside of that context. That means that if you want to use one variable name for multiple different and unrelated computations you may write functions that will do those computations. Lets look at another example:

```
void doSmth() {
    String var = "13";
    // you can do some work with this string variable
} 
// after you are done with the string and you want to do something else and you want to keep the name, you can write up a new function
void doSmthElse() {
    int var = -1;
    // you can now do something else with var as within this functions context there exists only one variable named "var" and it is an integer type
}
```

If your variables are connected in some way and you don't want to rename it for the sake of clarity you can make a function that will pass the first occurrence of var to the second one.

```
void doSmthRelated() {
    String var = "13";
    // do something with var
    // now you want to use var for something else and you want to keep the two connected variables named the same way

    // call the new function and pass the string as an argument
    relatedFunct(var);

    // if you need to use the value returned by the related function inside this function,
    // you will need to assign the returned value to a variable that doesn't share the name
    int necessaryValue = relatedFunct2(var);
}

void relatedFunct(String argument) {
    // you can now convert the passed argument to the type you need
    int var = Integer.parseInt(argument);
    // do something with var
}

int relatedFunct2(String argument) {
    // convert the argument and do whatever you want with the new var
    int var = Integer.parseInt(argument);
    // do something with var

    // and return the value so you can use it further in your main function
    return var;
}
```

I hope this helps clear some confusion with types, variable names and context.

EDIT: As user85421 pointed out `Integer.valueOf()` isn't the best way to convert a `String` to an `int`. It would be better to use `Integer.parseInt()`.